# How can I delete my custom search filter?

Tags: support, search, filtering, custom-filter

I just created a custom search filter just to see what it is.

But now I don't want it anymore...

I thought I could delete the custom search filter, but I can't find an option for that.

I'm stuck with this now...

> [image]

Is there a way to delete that?

Comment: This is some 11/10 use of freehand red lines.  Truly an excellent example of the medium.

Comment: @RyanM it kind of looks like a dapper [twitch icon](https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5968/5968952.png) wearing a hat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Navigate to your Custom Filter, then on the right (which I also use to navigate to the Filter in the below), below the hot meta posts, click the "bin" icon there:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a supplementary answer: you can use a userscript to add the relevant buttons and the functionality directly to the top dropdown. Inspired by your question, I wrote one ([available on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/9186/78873)) that adds the "delete" buttons to the custom filter items in the "more" dropdown:

[image: preview of the delete button added to the dropdown]

I think requiring a confirmation to delete one is a bit of an overkill so the script does not include one, but do let me know if this should be revisited in future versions.